# Xamarin Community Limitations

Tags: xamarin, filesize

I would like to ask if there is any user app size limitation for the Community edition of Xamarin Studio, because we had errors when trying to build the app in OXS.

Thank you in advnace!

Answer (score 3):

Quote from the Official announcement at [Xamarin for Everyone](https://blog.xamarin.com/xamarin-for-all/)

> Xamarin will be in every edition of Visual Studio, including the
>   widely-available Visual Studio Community Edition, which is free for
>   individual developers, open source projects, academic research,
>   education, and small professional teams. Develop and publish native
>   apps for iOS and Android with C# or F# from directly within Visual
>   Studio with ***no limits on app size***.